# Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to save into the database but I constantly get this error

Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

my controller

```
 $c = DB::table('subject_user')->where('user_id', $value)->first();

 $c->auth_teacher = '1';

 $c->save();
```

Comment: Do you have a Model created for the subject_user table?  The DB::table method won't return you an object that has a save method.

Comment: no I don't because that is a pivot table only I'm going directly to it

Comment: Unless you have a unique scenario, I'd try and do this using models.  It looks like you have pivot values on your many to many relationship.  Does the following stack thread help you at all.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21942374/3750476.  Your code might look like this.  $user->subjects()->updateExistingPivot($subject->id, array('auth_teacher' => 1), false);

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this approach

I haven't try `save` method with `where` condition. Hopefully, this approach may solve your problem.

```
 DB::table('subject_user')->where('user_id', $value)->update(['auth_teacher' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 12):

I just ran into the same problem and figured out the real Laravel answer.

The answer you've accepted here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41051946/470749) doesn't follow the truest Laravel way.

When I re-read the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-models, I noticed that `->save()` will work only if the way that I *retrieved* the object(s) was via the model like this:

```
$flights = App\Flight::where('active', 1)
           ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
           ->take(10)
           ->get();
```

There is no need to use `DB::table()` anywhere, and using it doesn't seem to be the recommended way.

So, you could change `DB::table('subject_user')->where` to `App\Subject_user::where` (or whatever is appropriate for you).

Comment: this is the more appropriate answer.

Comment: You don't seem to be able to use pessimistic locks with Eloquent models. If you need to prevent race conditions DB::table() is a must.

Comment: This was also helpful for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29166530/470749

Answer (score 2):

In case you started using DB:: instead of Model:: because you needed dynamic table name call, it is possible to use dynamic interface call instead, but I wonder if it is a good practice, anybody willing to explain if the following is wrong (since it works fine):

```
$model = 'User'; //Use the name of the model, not the table name
$interface_model = '\App\Models\\' . $model; //Needed to avoid the manual import of each model
$entry = $interface_model::where('id', $id)->first();
//$entry now support save()
```

Answer (score 1):

DB::table('subject_user')->where('user_id', $value)->update(['auth_teacher' => 1]);

I have been able to succeed with this.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here there are two ways of saving/updating records. In your case you would need to do the following: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#updates

```
$affected = DB::table('users')
              ->where('id', 1)
              ->update(['votes' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In some situations, Laravel Controller doesn't accept **find** method. Maybe you have tried on your controller.

**Solution-1)**
Try to use ***find method in the model***.

**Solution-2)**
Try to use **Where clause in Controller** instead of find.